# ERROR: for rabbitmq Cannot start service rabbitmq: driver failed programming external connectivity

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq

WARNING: Host is already in use by another container

ERROR: for rabbitmq  Cannot start service rabbitmq: driver failed programming external connectivity

Creating shopy-backend_db_1    ... done

Creating shopy-backend_redis_1 ... done

ERROR: for rabbitmq  Cannot start service rabbitmq: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint rabbitmq (4a8903254c20ef83fdd912bc2e22653ad1980de4a85021ce3bb993bab57993ba):
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5672: bind: address already in use

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.ca-backend_redis_1 ... done

ERROR: for rabbitmq  Cannot start service rabbitmq: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint rabbitmq (4a8903254c20ef83fdd912bc2e22653ad1980de4a85021ce3bb993bab57993ba): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5672: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you face this error it means that another rabbitmq service instance is running already and will be occupying port 5672.

You should stop the service as follows:

> sudo systemctl stop rabbitmq-server.service